# Show $\min _ {a, \mathbb F }= \frac1c f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $\mathbb K / \mathbb F $ is an arbitrary finite field extension. Prove that if $f \in \mathbb F [x]$ is irreducible of degree at least $1$ and $a \in \mathbb K $ is a root of $f$ then $\min _ {a, \mathbb F }= \frac1c f$ where $c$ is the leading coefficient of $f$.

I really have no clue for this one. I am guessing we can write $f=b_n x^n +...+ b_0$ where $n \in \mathbb N$. And of course $f$ is minimal $\iff$ irreducible, don't know if this helps though. So we are told $a$ is a root of $f$ so $f=b_n (a)^n + ... + b_1 (a) + b_0=0$.

Don't really know where I am going with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$. Then $p(x)|f(x)$ since $f(a)=0$. But $f$ is irreducible, so $p$ and $f$ must be equal up to a constant factor. The minimal polynomial is monic, so this constant must be $\frac{1}{c}$, where $c$ is the leading coefficient of $f$.

Comment: I understand up until where you said but f is irreducible.... if the minimum polynomial p is irreducible and f is irreducible, what do you mean by it must equal up to a constant factor? Do you mean p=f=constant? Could you explain this part more please.

Comment: $f(x)$ is irreducible, meaning that if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ then one of $g$ or $h$ must be a constant. Since $p(x)$ is non-constant and $p(x)$ divides $f(x)$, the other factor must be a constant.

Comment: Thanks I have a really important question. I was wondering if we can use this following corollary: *Suppose $K \subseteq L$ is a field extension and $u \in L$ is algebraic over $K$. Set $p=\min _{a, \mathbb K}$. If $f \in K[x]$ is monic irreducible and $f(u)=0$, then $f=p$ is the minimum polynomial of $u$ over $K$.* So we can let $p=\min_{a,\mathbb F}$. Our $f$ is irreducible and $p(a)=0$ so we need it to be monic. Let $f=a_0 +...+ a_nx^n = a_0 +...+ cx^n$. To make it monic, divide both sides by $c$ in which we get $\frac1c f$ which we have $p=\frac1c f $ by this corollary.This OK?

Comment: Yes, that looks good

Comment: with your proof, is its like p|f so there exists some constant k such that f=kp so p=f/k and then compare coefficients with the highest degree variable say $x^n$ (both f and p have the same degree since they're irreducible in the same field) and then when u compare coefficients with the highest degree term u get c/k=1 so k=c. So p=f/c. Note that $$f=cx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$$ and $$p=x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}...+b_0$$ is this correct?

Comment: p|f means f=kp, k would normally be a polynomial but since we have both f and p are irreducible, it must be a constant.

Comment: Yes, that looks good

Comment: my issue was that I dont know if f and p have the same degree. Do they have the same degree cuz they're both irreducible in the same field?

Comment: They have the same degree because $f=kp$ and $k$ is a constant.

Comment: I never mentioned this in my answer. Do you think I would lose marks? It does seem quite trivial to be fair...